# Proof that a Hilbert-Schmidt operator is a compact operator, and examples

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have the following definition and I want to prove the following proposition:

> **Definition:** Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, with basis $(e_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. We will say that $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt
> operator if $T:H\to H$ linear continuous, and \begin{equation*}
>      \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |T(e_{n})|^{2}<\infty. \end{equation*}
> **Proposition:** If $T$ is a H-S operator then $T$ is a compact operator.

I wrote the following proof, I would like to know if any detail escaped me, I would greatly appreciate the help:

> **Proof:** Let $T:H\to H$ be linear and continuous, we define the sequence of operators $(T_{m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by
>
> \begin{equation}
>          T_{m} e_{n} = 
>          \begin{cases}
>              Te_{n}     &   ,1\leq n\leq m\\
>              0          &   ,n>m
>          \end{cases} \end{equation} and also $(T_{m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a collection of finite range operators,  \begin{equation*}
>          T_{m}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}e_{n} \right) = T_{m}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{m} a_{n}e_{n} \right) \end{equation*} where
> the image of $T_{m}$ is generated by the collection
> $(T_{m}e_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N},n\leq m}$. Let's see that $T_{m}\to T$
> when $m\to \infty$, let's note that by linearity: \begin{eqnarray*}
>          (T-T_{m})\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n} \right)       & = &       T\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n} \right) - T_{m}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n} \right)   \\
>                                                                      & = &       T\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n} \right) - T\left( \sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n}e_{n} \right)            \\    
>                                                                      & = &       T\left( \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n} \right)                                                     \\
>                                                                      & = &       \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} a_{n} T(e_{n}) \end{eqnarray*}
>
> If we consider $x\in H$ such that $|x| = 1$, then we can note the
> following, let $\displaystyle x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n}$,
> \begin{eqnarray*}
>          \left| (T-T_{m})\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}e_{n} \right) \right|    & =  &      \left| \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} a_{n} T(e_{n})
>  \right|               \\
>                                                                                  &\leq&      \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty}         |a_{n}| |T(e_{n})|        
>  \\
>                                                                                  &\leq&      \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty}  |a_{n}|^{2}
>  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{n})|^{2}
>  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}           \\
>                                                                                  &\leq&      \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}    |a_{n}|^{2}
>  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{n})|^{2}
>  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}           \\
>                                                                                  &\leq&      \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}      a_{n}e_{n} \right| \left(
>  \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{n})|^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}          
>  \\
>                                                                                  &\leq&      \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{n})|^{2}
>  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \end{eqnarray*}
>
> Since $ T $ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, \begin{equation*}
>          \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{m})|^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |T(e_{m})|^{2}
>  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty \end{equation*} then \begin{equation*}
>          \left|(T-T_{m})(x)\right| \leq \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{m})|^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
>  |T(e_{m})|^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty \end{equation*} and
> since $\|T-T_{m}\|_{H^\star}$ is the smallest constant $K$ such that
> \begin{equation*}
>          \left|(T-T_{m})(x)\right| \leq K<\infty \end{equation*} then \begin{equation*}
>          \|T-T_{m}\|_{H^\star} \leq \left( \sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} |T(e_{m})|^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \end{equation*}
>
> and finally $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{n = m + 1}^{\infty} | T (e_ {m})
>  |^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\to 0$ when $ m \to \infty $, then $ \|
>  T-T_ {m} \| \to 0 $, and since $ T $ is the limit of finite range
> operators it is concluded that $ T $ is an operator compact.

I would also like to know if this class of operators becomes important later in the analysis, are there examples of H-S operators in infinite dimensional spaces ($L^{p}([a,b]), \ell^{p}([a,b]), \mathcal{C}([a,b])$, etc)?

And finally, is there a similar notion in non-separable Hilbert spaces? since in these spaces it is still possible to ensure the existence of an orthogonal basis (this requires Riesz-Fréchet, Hahn-Banach and Zorn's lemma).

Thanks for reading, anything is welcome

Comment: You may want to look over the equations again; the extra `>` are getting parsed into the math making this a very confusing read

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it was an error in the formatting code @MikaelÖhman

Comment: Regarding inseparable Hilbert spaces, I don't think there is much of a difference, nor do you need any stronger tools to prove the existence of an orthonormal basis (compared to infinite dimensional separable). The definition is the same, and they are still compact (do note that the range of a HS operator is always separable, though, so the kernel will be of countable codimension; the same is true for any compact operator, though).

Comment: Regarding non-Hilbert spaces: I don't think there is any (established) generalization of the notion to spaces without inner products (unlike compactness, which makes sense for continuous linear maps between arbitrary TVS; I also vaguely recall some uses in the non-linear case in the context of differential equations).